# Manually create provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I have a simple goal I would like to achieve, manually create a provisioning profile in Xcode.

So, I was trying to use the Pythonista Template in Xcode, and I wanted to flash it to one of my devices so that I could test it on a real device and not just the iOS simulator.

So I enter in what I want the app ID to be, and it says, No profiles for 'com.cartercoding.getnpostserver' were found. So I need to manually create a provisioning profile for it, which I have looked up, but the answers I have found are not relevant.

I am using Xcode 11, stable release.

Comment: Why don’t you create one the usual way? Do you understand what a provisioning profile does?

Comment: @Caleb I don't really know what a provisioning profile does, and I am trying to put an app that I downloaded from the internet on my phone, so I can't do it the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really know what a provisioning profile does...

A provisioning profile grants permission for one or more iOS devices to run an app signed with a specific certificate. Normally, an iOS device will *only* run apps that are signed by Apple; a provisioning profile tells the device that it may also run apps signed with a key corresponding to the certificate specified in the profile.

> I am trying to put an app that I downloaded from the internet on my phone, so I can't do it the usual way.

The whole iOS code signing infrastructure is designed to prevent you from doing that. Short of [jailbreaking](https://www.iphonehacks.com/jailbreak_iphone) your device (which is a whole other conversation) you can't just install an app that you've downloaded onto your phone.

> I have a simple goal I would like to achieve, manually create a provisioning profile in Xcode.

You can't create a provisioning profile "manually," if by that you mean to construct one on your own; you have to get one from Apple (whether that's automatically through Xcode or via the developer portal).

Answer (score 0):

For users who need to manually create a provisioning profile (in some companies every app has to have its own provisioning profile)

1. Sign in to your Apple Developer account and navigate to Certificates, IDs & Profiles > Identifiers > Provisioning Profiles.

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production

2. Add a new provisioning profile.
   [image]
3. Activate App Store.
   [image]
4. Click Continue.
   From the dropdown menu, select the app ID you just created.
5. Click Continue.
   Select the certificate you just created.
6. Click Continue.
   Fill in a name of your choice. The name is not visible to end users.
7. Click Generate.
   Download the provisioning profile.
8. Click Done.
   The provisioning profiles overview with your new provisioning profile is displayed.

---

If you need a Provisioning Profile of Type Ad Hoc

Is everything the same except point 3
[image]

These instructions were copied from this page
https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003598691-Creating-the-iOS-Provisioning-Profiles